# browser launch issue in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing this:
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

Error showing:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Myprojects\pythonProject.venv\Scripts\FirstTC.py", line 2, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
File "C:\Users\Ishita\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\Ishita\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 49, in **init**
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
File "C:\Users\Ishita\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

How to resolve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue with the way you are providing the path to the ChromeDriver executable. Additionally, you need to make sure to use double backslashes or a raw string for the path.

Here are a few steps to help you resolve this issue:

1. **Use a raw string for the path:**
   Instead of using a regular string, use a raw string by adding an 'r' prefix before the path. This helps in treating backslashes as literal characters.

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
2. **Double backslashes:**
   Alternatively, you can use double backslashes in the path.

   driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

Make sure to try one of these modifications and see if it resolves the issue. If the problem persists, there might be other factors contributing to the error, and additional investigation may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to how the webdriver.Chrome initialization is done. The path to the ChromeDriver executable should be passed as a separate argument, not directly within the parentheses.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Provide the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chrome_driver_path = r'C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe'

# Initialize the Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

# Now you can use the 'driver' object for further interactions
```

Make sure to replace r'C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe' with the actual path to your chromedriver.exe.
You can download the appropriate version of ChromeDriver from the official website: https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/